# problem with the installation of wireshark ubuntu "make" failed

Tags: permissions, install-from-source, wireshark

I need to install Wireshark but it seems to have some problems when I type `sudo make` command. Here is what I get:

```
dell@ubuntu:~/wireshark$ make
LANG=C /usr/bin/perl ./make-version.pl .
Version configuration file version.conf not found.  Using defaults.
This is not a SVN build.
svnversion.h is up-to-date.
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark'
Making all in tools
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/tools'
Making all in lemon
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/tools/lemon'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/tools/lemon'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/tools'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/tools'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/tools'
Making all in wsutil
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/wsutil'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/wsutil'
Making all in wiretap
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/wiretap'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/wiretap'
Making all in doc
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/doc'
Making all in epan
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/epan'
Making all in crc
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/epan/crc'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/epan/crc'
Making all in crypt
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/epan/crypt'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/epan/crypt'
Making all in ftypes
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/epan/ftypes'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/epan/ftypes'
Making all in dfilter
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/epan/dfilter'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/epan/dfilter'
Making all in dissectors
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/epan/dissectors'
make  all-am
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/epan/dissectors'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/epan/dissectors'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/epan/dissectors'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/epan'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/epan'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/epan'
Making all in plugins
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins'
Making all in asn1
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/asn1'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/asn1'
Making all in docsis
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/docsis'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/docsis'
Making all in ethercat
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/ethercat'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/ethercat'
Making all in giop
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/giop'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/giop'
Making all in gryphon
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/gryphon'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/gryphon'
Making all in irda
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/irda'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/irda'
Making all in m2m
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/m2m'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/m2m'
Making all in mate
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/mate'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/mate'
Making all in opcua
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/opcua'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/opcua'
Making all in profinet
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/profinet'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/profinet'
Making all in sercosiii
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/sercosiii'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/sercosiii'
Making all in stats_tree
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/stats_tree'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/stats_tree'
Making all in unistim
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/unistim'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/unistim'
Making all in wimax
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/wimax'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/wimax'
Making all in mux
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/mux'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/mux'
Making all in wimaxasncp
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/wimaxasncp'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins/wimaxasncp'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/plugins'
Making all in packaging
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/packaging'
Making all in macosx
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/packaging/macosx'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/packaging/macosx'
Making all in rpm
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/packaging/rpm'
Making all in SPECS
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/packaging/rpm/SPECS'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/packaging/rpm/SPECS'
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/packaging/rpm'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/packaging/rpm'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/packaging/rpm'
Making all in svr4
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/packaging/svr4'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/packaging/svr4'
Making all in nsis
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/packaging/nsis'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/packaging/nsis'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/packaging'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/packaging'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/packaging'
Making all in help
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/help'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/help'
Making all in codecs
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/codecs'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/codecs'
Making all in gtk
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark/gtk'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark/gtk'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dell/wireshark'
LANG=C /usr/bin/perl ./make-version.pl .
Version configuration file version.conf not found.  Using defaults.
This is not a SVN build.
svnversion.h is up-to-date.
/bin/bash ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -DINET6 -D_U_="__attribute__((unused))" -g -O2 -Wall -W -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wpointer-arith -Wno-pointer-sign -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wformat-security -I/usr/local/include -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12   -I/usr/include   -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o dftest dftest-dftest.o dftest-util.o  wiretap/libwiretap.la wsutil/libwsutil.la epan/libwireshark.la  -dlopen plugins/asn1/asn1.la -dlopen plugins/docsis/docsis.la -dlopen plugins/ethercat/ethercat.la -dlopen plugins/giop/cosnaming.la -dlopen plugins/giop/coseventcomm.la -dlopen plugins/gryphon/gryphon.la -dlopen plugins/irda/irda.la -dlopen plugins/m2m/m2m.la -dlopen plugins/mate/mate.la -dlopen plugins/mux/mux.la -dlopen plugins/opcua/opcua.la -dlopen plugins/profinet/profinet.la -dlopen plugins/sercosiii/sercosiii.la -dlopen plugins/stats_tree/stats_tree.la -dlopen plugins/unistim/unistim.la -dlopen plugins/wimax/wimax.la -lpcre -Wl,--export-dynamic -pthread -lgmodule-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0   -lm -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  -lpcap -lcares -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgcrypt -lgnutls -L/usr/lib -lsmi -lz 
libtool: link: rm -f .libs/dftest.nm .libs/dftest.nmS .libs/dftest.nmT
./libtool: line 3687: .libs/dftestS.c: Permission denied
./libtool: line 3823: .libs/dftest.nm: Permission denied
make[2]: *** [dftest] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dell/wireshark'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: May I ask a stupid question? Why aren't you installing wireshark from the Ubuntu repositories? It should be available in software center or simply by running `sudo apt-get install wireshark`.

Answer (score 1):

The following errors suggest me that you have messed up permissions while playing with `configure`, `make` and `sudo`:

```
./libtool: line 3687: .libs/dftestS.c: Permission denied
./libtool: line 3823: .libs/dftest.nm: Permission denied
```

To proceed, you have two ways:

1. Install [Wireshark](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wireshark/) from the official Ubuntu repositories (as [soulsource](https://askubuntu.com/users/17056/soulsource) suggested). This way, you won't have to build it manually and you'll also get automatic updates.
2. If you really want to build it yourself, then first get a clean environment:

   ```
   sudo make clean
   ```

   And start again:

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

   Remember that only the last command (`make install`) requires to be run as root.